# Could not authenticate user

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm having problem on using soap

I get an error:

Fault code: soap:Server
Fault string: Server was unable to process request. ---> ERROR: Could not authenticate user.

How to fix this? I dont know why this error appears. the last time i check my code its ok but now i got that error.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the info you provided, it looks like the provider of the service added authentication, you will need to contact them and request access.